# What is best practice for set properties in Custom element?

Tags: javascript, html, web, web-component, custom-element

Assume that I can create my own web component using Custom element (without any framework). For example something like:

```html
<extra-button size="3">Click here!</extra-button>
```

I can also provide property for changing `size` by using Javascript.
I can implement the property for using (changing size) in Javascript in style like this:

```js
button.size = 5;
```

or like this:

```js
button.setSize(5);
```

**Which way is the best practice?**

Comment: The former, since it is closest to the behaviour you would expect from a standard HTML Element. You can tie into attribute changes using the `attributesChangedCallback` hook available to all web components, so it's clearly meant to allow for these attributes to be set on-element. When designing web components, stick as closely as possible to what you'd want a native element to look like and the interface native elements provide as an example.

Comment: they are all good pratices

Comment: I personaly prefer to work with native setters/getters whenever I need reflection of properties and attributes

Comment: There is no right or wrong. It depends on your use case. Setters make for less programming errors because they always require one value. But they can **not** be chained: ``button.enable().setSize(5).setColor("green")`` It isn't too difficult to use Attribute notation **and** Getters/Setters (**and** as a bonus CSS property notation) See the [IconMeister](https://IconMeister.github.io) sourcecode on Github.